# Two number fields with trivial intersection, not linearly disjoint but....

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Do there exist two finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ such that $L\cap K=\mathbb{Q}$, the minimal polynomial $\mu_{\alpha}(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not irreducible over $K$, but $\mu_\alpha(\beta)\neq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Let $\alpha=\root3\of2$, let $\gamma$ be a nonreal cube root of 2, and let $\beta=\gamma+1$.

Comment: You're right. But actually I want that the factorization of $\mu_\alpha(X)$ over $K$ does not have any linear factor. I will ask another question.

Comment: New question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506769/two-number-fields-with-trivial-intersection-not-linearly-disjoint-but-cont